# HP Fortify 3.80: an internal error has occurred

Tags: java, token, fortify

My upload token expired and upon executing

```
./fortifyclient token -getoken AnalysisUploadToken -url"http://<localhost>/ssc" -user ssc_upload
```

I receive

```
An internal error has occurred.  
A JAXB unmarshalling exception; 
nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
```

I would show the rest, however it is approx. 200 lines.
The last time this happened (90 days ago), I used the 4.00 version of ./fortifyclient and it worked.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Is time synchronized between your client and server? I think that any operation with fortifyclient will fail if the time on the client and server differs by more than 5 or 10 minutes.
This will include checking the date and timezone as well.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem in both 3.80 and 4.00 versions of Fortify.  However, it suddenly allows me to generate a token after roughly 4 weeks of troubleshooting.  Happened 4 months ago and again now.  Time is synchronized and I can not find any other reason for this error.  It has been submitted to HP for work.  I will post any findings